# using "even if-clause" to express future

Tags: tense, past-tense, clauses, future-tense, subordinate-clauses

Here are three sentences with "even if". But what time does the action happen?

**Even if he go to the U.S.A, his wife is still in England now**.(This means the man will go to the U.S.A, right?)

**Even if he went to the U.S.A, his wife is still in England now**.(This means the man has already gone to the U.S.A.,right?)

**On July,1st,1994 , even if he went to the U.S.A, his wife still stayed in England.**(here plus "1994" to refer the old time, it means at that time the man would go to the U.S.A, but his wife was still in England,right?)

Thanks so much!

Comment: The first sample sentence is not grammatically correct; "go" is missing a tense for time.

Comment: sorry, I have changed the word to "even though" Thanks

Comment: "Even though" does not affect or modify _when_ he goes, it simply states that something _else_ happens despite it. It is still missing a tense for time.

Comment: It's still not correct.  "Even though he go" is not right.  Did he go in the past (in which case it should be *he went*) or is he going in the present (in which case it should be *he goes*)?

Comment: moyeea: Adding the word ***even*** makes absolutely no difference to either the meaning or the grammar, and the first sentence is still completely invalid as pointed out by @Harris.

Comment: I notice that in your paraphrasing you say ***but** his wife [remained]*, but in the "original" it's ***even though** he [went]*. I'm guessing that implies you don't understand the difference between **I'm poor but I'm honest** and **I'm honest but I'm poor**.

Comment: "Go" is an infinitive  verb, but in your top example  it need to simple past (went), or it could be future tense (will go) I believe you want to say in that example. "Even though he **will** go..."

Comment: On your last example you want the past participle (gone) but you would have to add the word 'had'   " in 1994, Even though he **had gone**..."

Comment: I'm really sorry， Let me change the  word to "even if"..

Answer (score 1):

> Even if he go*es* to the U.S.A, his wife is still in England now

There's a conditional happening here, but the second half of it is not expressed.

The speaker or writer is expecting you to figure out the main counterpart to "if he goes to the U.S.A." from the information "his wife is still in England now."

> Even if he goes to the U.S.A, his wife is still in England now, so X isn't going to go to the U.S.A.  (Example of something that could be meant.)

You would have to conclude he is not in the U.S.A. yet if we are talking about the possibility of him going to the U.S.A.

---

> Even if he went to the U.S.A, his wife is still in England now

There is a "past conditional" happening here - "if X happened, then Y had {not} happened."

But the speaker/writer is still expecting you to figure out the main counterpart to "if he went to the U.S.A." just like the present-tense version above.

> Even if he went to the U.S.A, his wife is still in England now, so I think that means he would not had actually gone to the U.S.A. (Example of something that could be meant.)

In this case though, he may have gone to the U.S.A. but the speaker/writer doesn't know that and believes it not to be the case.

---

We don't know the time he went to the U.S.A., or supposedly went to the U.S.A., unless that is stated.

Note that *even* is an intensifier and doesn't change the basic meaning of *if* or the conditional.

Comment: Thanks so much for your really kind help!  In the last sentence, I mean, now is 2016, and in 1994, from that time point. can I say:  Even if he went to the U.S.A, his wife was still in England.   You can say the first sentence from the present time point. But can I talk about one thing happened in the past? At that time, he was going to the U.S.A, but his wife was still here.

Comment: And I'm sorry. I mean, his wife should stay with her husband.  just change "in England" to " at home"  And the first one means "she should be at the airport now!" The second one means "why his wife didn't go???"  The third one is like changing the first one to the past.  All of them make sense and correct?

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is not grammatically correct, as "go" has no tense for time.

For both the second and third sentences, by the time the sentence is said, the man had already left (past tense). It does not tell us if he returned in either case.